# rename all file in a directory using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to Make a Python program that takes a folder name from the input argument, and then renames all its files by adding an "_{n}" at the end of it where n is the serial of that file. For example, if folder "images" contained, "images/cat.jpg", "images/dog.jpg", then after running the command, it will have "images/cat_1.jpg", "images/dog_2.jpg" . Sort the files according to last accessed date. I tried the problem partially as following:-

```
import os
from os import rename
from os.path import basename

path =  os.getcwd()
filenames =next(os.walk(path))[2]
countfiles=len(filenames)

for filename in filenames:
    fname=os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    ext=os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    old=fname+ext
    new=fname + '_' +ext
    os.rename(old, new)
```

this can rename the file adding an under score at the end of file name.However, I have no idea to add serial of files after the underscore. I would like to know how to batch rename the files using a simple Python script. I would appreciate any advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
import os
filepath = 'C:/images/'
os.chdir(filepath)
for num, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), start= 1):
    fname, ext = filename, ''
    if '.' in filename:
        fname, ext = filename.split('.')
    os.rename(filename, fname + '_%s' %num + '.' + ext)
```

Comment: would you please little more explain about 'enumerate()' function

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate What it does exactly it creates an extra variable (ie. makes your loop return a tuple containing (int, data)) where the left side is the index of the data. U can set it to start to any number you want (as I did, by giving this "1")

Comment: Dont you need `for num, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), 1):`? Your example won't run for me in python 2.7.12 without `os.getcwd()` added.

Comment: what argument 'os.listdir()' takes? I found an error after running the script **TypeError: listdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)**

Comment: Try: `os.listdir(filepath)`

Comment: @mmenschig I added 'os.getcwd()' and run it. I is working! however **.** before extension deleted after renaming complete. Have you any idea why it happened?

Comment: @mmenschig Yes, forgot. I was using it in python shell so it was working without getcwd()

Comment: [Solved] Thank you very much